# fetch not defined in Safari (ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fetch)

Tags: javascript, safari, fetch-api

For some reason `fetch` (https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) is not defined in Safari (Version 9.0.3), does anyone know why? It seems to be the standard and works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Can't seem to find anyone else having the same issue

I am using react with redux and here is some example code:

```
export function fetchData (url) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(loading())
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(response => {
      response.json()
      .then(data => {
        dispatch(success(data))
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch `fetch` is no supported by Safari.

Comment: two years ago and fetch is still not supported by safari... this browser is so pathetic!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/github/fetch polyfill for unsupported browsers.

```
npm install whatwg-fetch --save;
```

Edit: (per the comments)

add

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

in each file before using fetch – oliviergg

Comment: Thanks, should have known that.

Comment: I am using that (the es6-promise polyfill as well), but I keep getting that exact same error when viewing it on iOS.

Comment: (No edit available for comments..): Stock Android has the same issue.

Comment: @nickvda try adding `import 'whatwg-fetch';` before using fetch

Answer (score 4):

Use `whatwg-fetch` polyfill.
If you use `webpack`, you could just add it to entry point

```
entry: {
  app: ['whatwg-fetch', 'your-index.js']
}
```