# Fetch returning TypeError: Type error on iPhone 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am having an issue making an API call on the iPhone 5.

I have the following API call made inside a component

```
import FavouritesService from "../../api/FavouritesService";
const Favourites = () => {
  const getFavs = () => {
    favouritesService.getFavourites(0, 10, "FULL").then(response => {
      if (response.success === false) {
        //...
      } else {
        //...
      }
    });
  };
};

export default Favourites;
```

My `FavouritesService` that gets the api endpoint and calls a function inside an import is as follows.

```
import api from "./api";

class FavouriteService {
  getFavourites(page, pageSize, view) {
    return api.get(
      "/api/social-groups?page=" +
        encodeURIComponent(page) +
        "&pageSize=" +
        encodeURIComponent(pageSize) +
        "&view=" +
        encodeURIComponent(view) +
        "&type=FAVOURITE"
    );
  }
}

export default FavouriteService;
```

My `api.js` file where I do the API itself is as follows...

```
import _ from "lodash";
import "babel-polyfill";
import "isomorphic-fetch";

function handleErrors(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }
  return response;
}
function handleFetchError(error) {
  // Here is where I get TypeError: Type error
  if (error) {
    return { success: false, error: error };
  }
}

function payloadOptions(method, body) {
  var postBody = body;
  var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  if (typeof postBody === "object") {
    postBody = JSON.stringify(postBody);
    contentType = "application/json";
  }
  return {
    method: method,
    body: postBody,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": contentType
    }
  };
}

const defaultOptions = {
  redirect: "error",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json"
  }
};

class API {
  request(url, options) {
    return fetch(url, _.defaultsDeep(options || {}, defaultOptions))
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(handleFetchError);
  }

  get(url, options) {
    return this.request(
      url,
      _.defaultsDeep(options || {}, payloadOptions("GET"))
    );
  }
}

export default new API();
```

This is where the error occurs in the `handleFetchError`, `error` returns  `TypeError: Type error`. When I `console.log` this, that's all I get, I'm not able to drill down any further to actually inspect what's actually happened here.

I've tried to google this but no one else seems to have this specific issue so I assume I have gone wrong at some step when making this GET request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for some time.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to use a polyfill to allow me to fetch.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35830329/3113377) helped to figure out I had to install `whatwg-fetch`